# PHP if statement not working?

Tags: php, arrays

```
// 40 characters string combine by 5 different fields
$field1 = apple;
$field2 = orange;
$field3 = pineapple;
$field4 = banana;
$field5 = strawberry;

// fields will be separated with a comma
$string = implode(", ", array_filter(array($field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5)));

// string will be cut off at about 15th characters then make a break line           
$stringList = explode("\n", wordwrap($string , 15));

// 1st rowField takes the 1st line of string
$rowField1 = array_shift($nutritionalList);
$string = implode(" ",$stringList );
$stringList = explode("\n", wordwrap($string , 25));
$rowField2 = "From 1st Row continued" . "\n" . implode("\n", $stringList) . "\n \n";}
```

This Output will show:

```
$rowField1 = "apple, orange"
$rowField2 = "From 1st Row continued \n pineapple, banana, strawberry"
```

However, my problem is if `$field3`, `$field4`, and `$field5` are NULL, I don't want to display `$rowField2` including the text "From 1st Row continued"

I tried IF/ELSE and ISSET procedure:

```
if (isset($stringList)) {
   $rowField2 = "From 1st Row continued\n" . implode("\n", $stringList) . "\n\n";
}
else {
   $rowField2 = NULL;
}
```

But `$rowField2` still shows "From 1st Row continued". I want it not to display that if the last 3 fields are NULL.

Comment: Is it deliberate that you wrote e.g. `$field1 = apple;` rather than `$field1 = "apple";`? I don't see those constants defined.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: sorry about the typo. was re-typing the code as fast as i can to get my question out quick. anyways, shashank's solution worked for me. so i'm happy :) thanks for viewing

Comment: You can click "edit" above to fix the code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will give output as "apple, orange".

is it fine?

```
<?php
$field1 = 'apple';

$field2 = 'orange';

$field3 = '';

$field4 = '';

$field5 = '';

// fields will be seperated with a comma

$string = implode(", ", array_filter(array($field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5)));

// string will be cut off at about 15th characters then make a break line

$stringList = explode("\n", wordwrap($string , 15));

// 1st rowField takes the 1st line of string

$rowField1 = array_shift($stringList);

$string = implode(" ",$stringList );

$stringList = explode("\n", wordwrap($string , 25));

$rowField2 = ( isset( $stringList[0] ) && !empty($stringList[0]) ) ? "From 1st Row continued" . "\n" . implode("\n", $stringList) . "\n \n" : '';
echo $rowField1;
echo "<br />";
echo $rowField2;
exit;
?>
```

Comment: -1: [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Actually I'll take back the -1 as I now notice he's working on an array... but I still wouldn't recommend `empty`.

Comment: yes you are write you can also put $stringList[0] != '' in place of empty.

Comment: @Shashank: `count($stringList)` is more canonical. What if there's an array with non-numeric keys? Or an array with non-contiguous numeric keys that start higher than `0`? You're introducing criteria into your code that do not need to be there.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used condition :

```
if( isset($stringList) && count($stringList) > 0 ){
    // blah blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$stringList` will always be *set*, but it won't always have content in it.

Don't use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) because it's not clear from reading it what it does — for one thing, `empty("0")` is `TRUE`! — , even though in this case, on an array, it would work.

My recommended approach:

```
if (count($stringList)) {
   $rowField2 = "From 1st Row continued\n" . implode("\n", $stringList) . "\n\n";
}
else {
   $rowField2 = NULL;
}
```